# Download unique data into ms access table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using this code to download certain outlook mail fields into access. This works well however the code is keep on downloading duplicate mails. Is there a way to check for existing records and download records which are not in the table? Your answers would help a lot in my project

```vb
Private Sub getml()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application

Dim inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim inboxItems As Outlook.Items
Dim Mailobject As Object
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim dealer As Integer
Set db = CurrentDb

Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set inbox = OlApp.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set rst= CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("mls")
Set inboxItems = inbox.Items
For Each Mailobject In inboxItems

    With rst
        .AddNew
        !task= Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("taskID")
        !tsktml= Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("timeline")
        .Update

        Mailobject.UnRead = False
    End With
End If
Next
Set OlApp = Nothing
Set inbox = Nothing
Set inboxItems = Nothing
Set Mailobject = Nothi
End Sub
```

Comment: Each ITEM will have a `ConversationID` which is unique to that item - it will look something like **2002F3A5F78D45EBA44C273A54AFB802**.  This ID will only change if you move the item to another folder - I've got code somewhere that will track the ID change, but if the item doesn't move it makes a useful unique identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that `TaskID` is a numeric unique identifier for tasks, not that familiar with Outlook objects. If so, you can use the following code to first check the task hasn't been imported already.

```vb
Private Sub getml()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application

    Dim inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim inboxItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim Mailobject As Object
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim dealer As Integer
    Set db = CurrentDb

    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set inbox = OlApp.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set rst= CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("mls")
    Set inboxItems = inbox.Items
    For Each Mailobject In inboxItems

        With rst
            .FindFirst "task =""" & Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("taskID") & """"
            If .NoMatch
                .AddNew
                !task= Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("taskID")
                !tsktml= Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("timeline")
                .Update

                Mailobject.UnRead = False
            End If
        End With
    End If
    Next
    Set OlApp = Nothing
    Set inbox = Nothing
    Set inboxItems = Nothing
    Set Mailobject = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually taskid is a field which contains data like "task-1234" it's a combination of text and number separated with a hyphen. Now no mails are getting downloaded if you don't mind can you help me out.

Comment: Try the current edit. Extra quotes are added to the `.FindFirst` argument to account for it being a string.

Comment: I am getting an error message as 91: object variable or with block variable not set in the line ".FindFirst "task =""" & Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("taskID") & """" can you help me out. I tried setting a dim variant however it not helping me. Could you assist me on that.